# R: Applying filter on multiple variables at the same time

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Consider the following data.

```
x1 <- c("V", "v", "X", "x")
x2 <- c("x", "V", "X", "v")
x3 <- 1:4

df <- data.frame(x1 ,x2 ,x3)
```

I would like to obtain all those observations that contain a `V` or `v` within both variables `x1` and `x2`. I know I can use the subsequent code which will yield the desired result:

```
valid <- c("V", "v")

df %>% 
  filter(x1 %in% valid) %>% 
  filter(x2 %in% valid)
```

However, in my real data I will need to apply this filter across many variables, so I would like to declare a vector `vars` and apply the filtering to all these `vars` at once.

```
vars <- c("x1", "x2")

df %>% 
  filter(all(vars %in% valid))
```

The code above does not work as `filter()` can not take character vectors as input, but maybe there is an equivalent to `all_of()` and `any_of()` that can be used with character vectors in combination with `select()`.

I would appreciate any solution. Lukas

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% filter(if_any(vars, ~. == valid))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
valid <- c("V", "v")
vars <- c("x1", "x2")

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(all_of(vars),~ .%in% valid))

  x1 x2 x3
1  v  V  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on what `~ .%in%` does? Is there a nice resource to learn about this specific syntax conventions?

Comment: @LukasUnterschuetz its a function ie. `~.x %in% valid` ie `function(x) x%in% valid`